# Error: Editing data cache miss for key; Unable to get editing data for preview {"key":"<GUID>"}

Tags: nextjs, vercel

After upgrading from JSS 20 to JSS 21, we are unable to open pages in Experience Editor.

[image: EE error]

Our rendering host is Vercel and there are several errors in the logs:

Error 1:

```
T',
  maxHeaderSize: undefined,
  insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
  joinDuplicateHeaders: undefined,
  path: '/?timestamp=1708526618306',
  _ended: true,
  res: [IncomingMessage],
  aborted: false,
  timeoutCb: null,
  upgradeOrConnect: false,
  parser: null,
  maxHeadersCount: null,
  reusedSocket: false,
  host: 'clientname.vercel.app',
  protocol: 'https:',
  _redirectable: [Writable],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
  [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
  [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
  [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype],
  [Symbol(errored)]: null,
  [Symbol(kHighWaterMark)]: 16384,
  [Symbol(kRejectNonStandardBodyWrites)]: false,
  [Symbol(kUniqueHeaders)]: null
},
data: '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charSet="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/><title>404: NotFound</title><meta name="next-head-count" content="3"/></html>'
 },
 isAxiosError: true,
 toJSON: [Function: toJSON]
  }
 Hint: for non-standard server or Next.js route configurations, you may need to override the 'resolveServerUrl' or 'resolvePageUrl' available on the 'EditingRenderMiddleware' config.
```

Error 2:

```
    Editing data cache miss for key 0893e6d7-8a9d-471f-ba1f-557b7d0990c2-jrtspdrkb1 at /tmp/if-you-need-to-delete-this-open-an-issue-sync-disk-cache/editing-data
Error: Unable to get editing data for preview {"key":"0893e6d7-8a9d-471f-ba1f-557b7d0990c2-jrtspdrkb1"}
at Object.exec (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:643:10076)
at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309586
at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
at async Object.create (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309498)
at async getStaticProps (/var/task/.next/server/pages/[[...path]].js:1:2912) {


page: '/'
}
Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/.next/server/pages/500.js'
Require stack:
- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js
- /var/task/___next_launcher.cjs
- /opt/node-bridge/chunk-N3ULQXIM.js
- /opt/node-bridge/chunk-5UAC7W5H.js
- /opt/node-bridge/vercel-tla.js
- /var/task/___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
    at /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:15:28048
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at exports.b (/opt/node-bridge/chunk-5UAC7W5H.js:1:1033)
    at /opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-BGIDXK2J.js:1:1443
    at Function.Re (/opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-BGIDXK2J.js:1:1809)
    at e.<computed>.L._load (/opt/node-bridge/bridge-server-BGIDXK2J.js:1:1413)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1225:19)
    at w.require (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:15:28264)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js',
    '/var/task/___next_launcher.cjs',
    '/opt/node-bridge/chunk-N3ULQXIM.js',
    '/opt/node-bridge/chunk-5UAC7W5H.js',
    '/opt/node-bridge/vercel-tla.js',
    '/var/task/___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js'
  ]
}
Error: Unable to get editing data for preview {"key":"0893e6d7-8a9d-471f-ba1f-557b7d0990c2-jrtspdrkb1"}
    at Object.exec (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:643:10076)
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309586
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
    at async /var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309576
    at async Object.create (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/3853.js:66:309498)
    at async getStaticProps (/var/task/.next/server/pages/[[...path]].js:1:2912) {
  page: '/'
}
Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to us having unchecked "Automatically expose System Environment Variables":

[image: sys env vars false]

We had done this previously due to adverse effects on next-auth-js. We were unable to override the PUBLIC_URL that it retrieved as it kept pulling the Vercel Domain and we rely on Cloudflare to proxy into Vercel with a .com (whereas Vercel provides a *.vercel.app domain OOTB).

This setting affects which instance of the Editing Data Service is used. With the `ServerlessEditingDataService` being required for Vercel. With process.env.VERCEL hidden, we were defaulting to `BasicEditingDataService` thus causing us the error.

https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/packages/sitecore-jss-nextjs/src/editing/editing-data-service.ts

So, if we check this box it breaks next-auth-js, but if we uncheck it, it breaks Experience Editor.

Our solution was to leave the checkbox *unchecked* and to instead manually add the variable VERCEL with a value of "1". This satisfies the condition in Sitecore-JSS and still allows next-auth-js to work properly.

[image: Vercel equals one]

It is worth noting that Sitecore JSS relies on a few other VERCEL system variables as well.

- VERCEL_ENV: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/packages/create-sitecore-jss/src/templates/nextjs-multisite/src/lib/middleware/plugins/multisite.ts
- VERCEL_URL: https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/dev/packages/sitecore-jss-nextjs/src/utils/utils.ts